# Getting the relevant error message using .net SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using Facebook ads api SDK for .net (http://www.nuget.org/packages/Facebook/6.4.2) and when I catch an error, the message is always the same general error in the exception message object:

> (FacebookApiException - #100) Invalid parameter

It happens since I moved to the versioned calls (v2.2) - before that I used the unversioned calls and it was fine. For example, this is how I get the error (using regular try catch in c#):

```
try
{
    FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient();
    facebookClient.AccessToken = "<YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN>"

    Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    string name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    parameters.Add("name", name);
    parameters.Add("conversion_specs", "");
    parameters.Add("campaign_id", "6024570447800");
    parameters.Add("creative", "{\"creative_id\":\"6024570452200\"}");
    parameters.Add("redownload", "false");
    parameters.Add("tracking_specs", "");
    parameters.Add("view_tags", "[]");

    var result = facebookClient.Post("v2.2/act_107893676040337/adgroups", parameters) as IDictionary<string, object>;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    FacebookApiException fbEx = ex as FacebookApiException;
    string errorMsg = fbEx.Message;
}
```

It happens because Facebook changed the return error object and added 2 new fields: error_user_title, error_user_msg.
Is there a way to access these fields in the FacebookApiException object ?
How can I extract the relevant error message?

Comment: In the particular sample you're making, conversion_specs and tracking_specs are wrong. The Facebook Graph API is expecting a JSON Object and you're just sending an empty string. I would just not specify them altogether since they're not required for this POST call. I would take a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adgroup/v2.2

As for the .NET sample, I can't help you there, since I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dived into this issue and it's not a Facebook problem. The problem is in the third party SDK.

I contacted the development team, they aware of this issue and fixed it in the last beta version.